# Решение логистической регрессии

Tags: машинное-обучение, статистика

Правильно я понимаю, что логистическую регрессию можно решать способом градиентного спуска и аналитическим методом(то есть считая логарифм шансов)? Или это все один метод?

Answer (score 1):

Любая регрессионная модель строиться (не решается, а именно строиться) основываясь на минимизации некоторого функционала, который называют функцией потерь. Такую задачу всегда можно решить с помощью методов численной оптимизации, градиентный спуск -  один из ее разновидностей, не всегда самый лучший с точки зрения точности, сходимости и пр.
Для простых случаев - та же линейная регрессия, квадратичная, логарифмическая и пр -  задачу можно (более менее) легко решить алгоритмически. Использовать такое решение (если оно есть)  всегда и проще, и точнее, и эффективнее в плане ресурсов. Сможете ли вы ее решить аналитически для логистической регрессии? Ну, если сумеете -  то все ОК, если нет - то ее всегда можно решить численными методами.

Если говорить вообще, то любая нейронная сеть (не важно для какой задачи)  -  это сложная функция, у которой можно найти значения коэффициентов, минимизирующих ее ошибку. Вот только смысла это делать тогда, когда задача решается явно -  нет никакого, кроме погони за модой. А когда эту минимизацию провести очень сложно -  вот тут и место для нейромоделей.

Comment: 1/(1+e^(-x)) это равносильная замена использованию логарифму шансов? Другими словами, когда мы используем градиентный спуск, мы используем шансы для решения оптимизационной задачи?

Comment: Ваш "уточняющий" вопрос сформулирован так, что ответить на него невозможно в принципе. Вернее, можно одним словом "нет". Потому что "шансы" и "градиентный спуск"  -  не пересекаются от слово "совсем".  Градиентный спуск используется на этапе обучения сети, шансы возникают при ее использовании.